# What is the commonjs equivalent of doing var = return await myAsyncFunction() outside of asyncfunction?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, top-level-await

I am trying to connect my express router functions to ReactJS. Currently my code Looks Like this:

**nftmodule.js**

```
import {ZDK} from '@zoralabs/zdk'




const zdk = new ZDK("https://api.zora.co/graphql")

export async function fetchTokens(zdk, collectionAddresses){
  return await zdk.tokens({
    where: {
      collectionAddresses
    }
  })
} 

const tokens = await fetchTokens(zdk, '0x42069ABFE407C60cf4ae4112bEDEaD391dBa1cdB')

export function aToken(){
  return tokens
}
```

Then it pops into here

**nftwholecollection.js**

```
import { aToken, fetchTokens} from './nftmodule.js'
import {ZDK} from '@zoralabs/zdk'

const zdk = new ZDK("https://api.zora.co/graphql")

let token = await fetchTokens(zdk, '0x42069ABFE407C60cf4ae4112bEDEaD391dBa1cdB')
let thistoken = JSON.stringify(token,null,3)
console.log(JSON.parse(thistoken).tokens.nodes[3].token.image)


let collectionSize = 40;


const tokens = aToken()

let nftGallery = JSON.stringify(tokens,null,3)
let x

export function loopLinks()
{
  let output =""
    for(x =0;x<collectionSize; x++)
    if (JSON.parse(nftGallery).tokens.nodes[x].token.image.mediaEncoding.__typename != "UnsupportedEncodingTypes") {
    output = output + `<img src=${JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(nftGallery).tokens.nodes[x].token.image.mediaEncoding.thumbnail)} loading='lazy'>`
    }
    return output
}
console.log(loopLinks())
```

then finally
**nftrouter.js**

```
import {loopLinks} from './nftwholecollection.js'
import express from 'express'

console.log(loopLinks())


const app = express();
const port = 5150;


app.get('/api/nft',(req,res)=>{
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")
  res.write(loopLinks())
  res.end()
})

app.listen( port ,()=>{
    console.log("the server got 5150'd")
});
```

It seems that I have two options here. I can either figure out how to get my modules to appear in react.js or I can figure out how to write the above code in commonjs.
I am attempting to do the latter.

I have run into several issues all basically centered around trying to figure out the common js equivalent of "let token = await fetchTokens(zdk, 'blablablacrypto')"

When I tried to set the type to commonjs in packagejson I obviously got an error in nftmodule about not being able to reference await outside of the body of the async function in commonjs. What is the commonjs solution for this?

Comment: Hi.  I did not understand your motivation to more your seemingly perfectly OK Express-in-ES-modules implementation to CommonJS.  Just do Express in ES Modules as you have it and the server will work.  Then just fetch from React.  What am I missing here?

Comment: use `promise.then` syntax ... or `(aysnc() => { your code that uses await })()` - of course, either way you'll need to do some other rewriting of your code

Comment: You've created a cyclic dependency between `nftmodule` and `nftwholecollection`. I recommend removing that first.

Comment: @morganney ahh shucks I copied in the nftrouter code twice! my mistake I will edit the psot

Comment: If you want to rely on top level await to ensure the tokens are available to dependent modules then do `export default await fetchTokens()` in nftmodule.js. Then the other modules import the exported `token` instead of the functions for fetching a token.

Comment: @JoséRamírez I think I thought it would be much more of an undertaking because Node defaults to common js so I got freaked out. It's actually fine though

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this to use top level await.

**nftmodule.js**

```js
import {ZDK} from '@zoralabs/zdk'

const zdk = new ZDK("https://api.zora.co/graphql")

async function fetchTokens(zdk, collectionAddresses){
  return await zdk.tokens({
    where: {
      collectionAddresses
    }
  })
} 

// Here we use top level await
export default await fetchTokens(zdk, '0x42069ABFE407C60cf4ae4112bEDEaD391dBa1cdB')
```

**nftwholecollection.js**

```js
// Now this module will wait for the promise to resolve before executing
import tokens from './nftmodule.js'

let collectionSize = 40;

let nftGallery = JSON.stringify(tokens,null,3)
let x

export function loopLinks()
{
  let output =""
    for(x =0;x<collectionSize; x++)
    if (JSON.parse(nftGallery).tokens.nodes[x].token.image.mediaEncoding.__typename != "UnsupportedEncodingTypes") {
    output = output + `<img src=${JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(nftGallery).tokens.nodes[x].token.image.mediaEncoding.thumbnail)} loading='lazy'>`
    }
    return output
}
console.log(loopLinks())
```

**nftrouter.js** (the same as before)

```js
import {loopLinks} from './nftwholecollection.js'
import express from 'express'

console.log(loopLinks())


const app = express();
const port = 5150;


app.get('/api/nft',(req,res)=>{
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")
  res.write(loopLinks())
  res.end()
})

app.listen( port ,()=>{
    console.log("the server got 5150'd")
});
```